# How do I query a specific item in the dataLayer with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I'm trying to extract a specific item's value from the dataLayer.  This actually works: **dataLayer[26].discountCode**  BUT the problem is the item position in the array changes (sometimes it's 26, other's it's 27, 28) - My question is how can I always choose the correct item.  The event pair I'm seeking is :

```
[array #]: {event: "e_orderDiscount", discountCode: "20"}
```

edit:
I tried: `Tried this: const company = dataLayer.find(e => e.event === 'company_name'); const thename = company.company_name;`  but results were not what I was expecting.  This  `dataLayer.find(e => e.company_name).company_name` eventually was the solution I needed.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, ideally as [mre]. Are you using Array.find()?

Comment: The search item has changed a bit. This is where I'm at.  I'm trying to find a value for "company_name", which is in the dataLayer at location 12. As I understand it - dataLayer is an unstable thing and the position in the array could change.  This works: dataLayer[12].company_name   BUT what if it isn't #12 on a subsequent page load?

Comment: Also -- when I try this: 
const company = dataLayer.find(e => e.event === 'company_name');
const thename = company.company_name;

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_name' of undefined" error message.

Comment: That error means there's no match. Look, I don't mean to be rude, but this is an extremely basic issue, and the amount of time we're wasting is in no way proportional to this. Provide some example input, and we will fix this in seconds.

Comment: OK -- Here's a portion of the dataLayer that I'm trying to access: (sorry can't format this in the comments)  this is dataLayer[13] in the array.

>13: 
annual_sales: 000000
city: "chicago"
country: "US"
company_name: "Acme Tools"
Industry: "construction"

Comment: You can always add it to your question. Anyway, to find the above element, you need `const company = dataLayer.find(e => e.company_name === 'Acme Tools');`

Comment: Thank you.. but when I run that in my console I get "undefined".  Also the company name is unknown to me.  I need to retrieve the value of  "company_name".  - I'm trying to personalize a page, based on the company.  some foo code:  if (company_name === "Acme Tools") {do something};  if (company_name === "Amazon") {do something else} etc..

Comment: ....seriously, we keep wasting time here. You need to add a proper example of `dataLayer` to your question or all I can do is wildly guess. Alternatively, you need to properly describe what you're actually looking for. For instance like this: "I have an array of elements. Each element has a different structure. Only a single element has a `company_name` property of unknown value. How can I find this element, and consequently the company name?"

Comment: If that is indeed what you're looking for, you need `const company = dataLayer.find(item => item.hasOwnProperty('company_name'));` as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/a35dn7th/ (if this is *still* not what you're looking for, please provide a proper example of input and desired output **in your question** or I'll flag it for closure)

Comment: ...thanks I got it figured out.  This worked: dataLayer.find(e => e.company_name).company_name  adding the key to the end of the find, returned it's key pair value.  As for my example -- I did provide the basic structure of the dataLayer item as it appears in it's Array, which I was trying to target.  I simply needed to know how to query the data. If you felt this was a waist of your time, I'm sorry, but you weren't obligated to answer. I do appreciate the time you put into this question.

Comment: When it comes to finding a specific element in an array, it is absolutely crucial to state how that specific items *differs* from the other items. You never clearly stated this. You instead said `I'm trying to find a value for "company_name"`, which is very misleading. Since you didn't comment on this at all, here it is again: `"I have an array of elements. Each element has a different structure. Only a single element has a company_name property of unknown value. How can I find this element, and consequently the company name?"`

Comment: ah..so, if there was more than one '"company_name"' in the dataLayer (regardless if the values are the same or not) -- does it just return the first instance or does it return all instances?

Comment: [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return the first match, `.filter` returns an array containing all matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the back and forth in the comments, this was the solution that worked:

```
dataLayer.find(e => e.company_name).company_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for an item, you can use `Array.prototype.find`:

```
// Watch out, item could be undefined if there are none that match
const item = dataLayer.find(e => e.event === 'e_orderDiscount');
const code = item.discountCode;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: If your answer is basically a shortened copy of the docs page, please consider not posting an answer at all. SO is not supposed to rehash docs. If you want to help OP, do so in a comment instead, please.

Comment: @ChrisG Apologies, I thought comments were more for questions, clarifications, or half-answers. I'll remember this for the future.

Comment: @ChrisG - could you explain this more? I keep getting undefined errors.